# Creating Columns based on TypeID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This may get confusing but I'm pretty sure one of you guys can help me out with this. So basically, I have this main table consisting of the following:

```
ObjID, InfoID, InfoVal, (other columns not needed).

When InfoID = 1, the InfoVal for that row represents the Report name. 
When InfoID = 4, the InfoVal for that row represents the Stored Procedures Name.
When InfoID = 16,17,23 or 24, the InfoVal for that row represents the Email for that Report.
```

My Question is, how do I exactly convert each condition into a column and join it all together? So far I have multiple separate queries with a WHERE condition for the InfoID = ?? and I'd like to join each column together.

Essentially, I'd like a Column for Report Name, Stored Procedure Name and a column for the Email.

If you need pictures to visualize let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and your expcted  result

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select objid,
       max(case when infoid = 1 then infoval end) as report_name,
       max(case when infoid = 4 then infoval end) as stored_procedure_name,
       max(case when infoid = 16 then infoval end) as email1,
       max(case when infoid = 17 then infoval end) as email2,
       max(case when infoid = 23 then infoval end) as email3,
       max(case when infoid = 24 then infoval end) as email4
from t
group by objid;
```

To filter:

```
select t.*
from (select objid,
             max(case when infoid = 1 then infoval end) as report_name,
             max(case when infoid = 4 then infoval end) as stored_procedure_name,
             max(case when infoid = 16 then infoval end) as email1,
             max(case when infoid = 17 then infoval end) as email2,
             max(case when infoid = 23 then infoval end) as email3,
             max(case when infoid = 24 then infoval end) as email4
      from t
      group by objid
    ) t
where email1 like . . .
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, this was exactly what I was looking for. I have one more question though, how or where should I use a WHERE clause to get rid of extra gunk? There some non emails that are appearing and I cannot add a WHERE part to the case and the column name is not being picked up in my where clause. I need to implement something like this:  WHERE email like '@somewhere.com' to the query. 

Thank You.

Comment: @LifeOfJona . . . If you want a `WHERE` clause, use a subquery.  Otherwise, use a `HAVING` clause.  In SQL Server, I think you need to repeat the entire expression.

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure how to implement this subquery. Mind helping me?

Comment: Would I have to add all of this into a temp table and then do a WHERE clause of what I'd like?

edit; just seen the filter! Thank You!